# Inserting new score into sorted array while updating separate array of names

Tags: c++

`score` is an array of 10 scores in ascending order.
`scoreName` is an array of names associated with with each score.
I need to check if a new score is good enough to enter the the high score table and if so, insert it into the correct position and make sure `scoreName` is also updated to reflect any changes.

I am having problems with my current code:

//Table

```
for (int i = 0; i < leaderBoardSize; i++)
        {
            cout << scoreName[i] << "\t\t" << score[i] << endl;
        }
        system("pause");

        //Check to see if you made the highScore
        if (diceTotal >= score[9])
        {
        cout << "Congrats, you have made the HighScore Table !\nEnter Your Name.";

            cin >> playerName;

            for (int i = 9; i < leaderBoardSize; i--)
            {

                if (diceTotal <= score[i])
                {
                    scoreName[i = i + 1] = scoreName[i];
                    score[i = i + 1] = score[i];

                    scoreName[i] = playerName;
                    score[i] = diceTotal;
                    break;
                }

                    scoreName[i = i + 1] = scoreName[i];
                    score[i = i + 1] = score[i];


            }
        }

Here is the entire code:
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //dice game variables
    int dice1 = 0;
    int dice2 = 0;
    int diceTotal = 0;
    int round = 0;

    string choice;
    bool isDone = true;

    //Scoreboard 
    const int leaderBoardSize = 10;
    int score[10] = { 40, 33, 29, 24, 22, 19, 15, 12, 11, 9 };
    string scoreName[leaderBoardSize] = { "Jason", "Steve", "Bob", "Timberduck",    "Eric", "Susan", "Tyler", "Nick", "NinjaDave", "RaidenGunfire" };
    string playerName;



    //random number seeder
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));



    //Game instructions
    cout << "dice game\n---------\nCreated By: Darcy Tellier\n--------------------------\nInstructions:\nRoll 2 dices. Try to get as close to 50 without going over." << endl;

    //The Game loop
    do
    {
        //resets game variables
        diceTotal = 0;
        round = 1;

        //in game match loop
        do
        {
            // display round #, current dice total, ask user to quit or re-roll.
            cout << "Round\n-----\n  " << round << endl;
            cout << "current total:" << diceTotal << endl;
            cout << "Roll dice (y/n)?";
            cin >> choice;

            //Checks the users imput for invalid characters 
            while (choice != "Y" && choice != "y" && choice != "N" && choice != "n")
            {
                cout << "invalid option. Choose y/n:" << endl;
                cin >> choice;
            }


            if (choice == "Y" || choice == "y")
            {
                //roll dice
                round += 1;
                dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                diceTotal = diceTotal + dice1 + dice2;
                cout << "you have rolled a " << dice1 << " and a " << dice2 <<   endl;

                if (diceTotal > 50)
                {
                    isDone = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //break was used because "isDone = false" does not work here. The debugger shows that when the variable is set to false, it still ignores it and skips  to the next round. 
                break;
            }

        } while (isDone == true || diceTotal < 50);

        //end of round
        if (diceTotal > 50)
        {
            cout << "\nGameOver" << endl;
            cout << "You went over in " << round << " turns. You Lose!!! " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You stopped at " << round << " turns. Final score: " <<  diceTotal << "." << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
        //Table

        for (int i = 0; i < leaderBoardSize; i++)
        {
            cout << scoreName[i] << "\t\t" << score[i] << endl;
        }
        system("pause");

        //Check to see if you made the highScore
        if (diceTotal >= score[9])
        {
            cout << "Congrats, you have made the HighScore Table !\nEnter Your       Name.";

            cin >> playerName;

            for (int i = 9; i < leaderBoardSize; i--)
            {

                if (diceTotal <= score[i])
                {

                    scoreName[i] = playerName;
                    score[i] = diceTotal;
                    break;
                }




            }
        }
        //board display #2
        for (int i = 0; i < leaderBoardSize; i++)
        {
            cout << scoreName[i] << "\t\t" << score[i] << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
        //do you want to play again?
        cout << "Do you want to play again";
        cin >> choice;
        while (choice != "Y" && choice != "y" && choice != "N" && choice != "n")
        {
            cout << "invalid option. Choose y/n:" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        }

        if (choice == "Y" || choice == "y")
        {
            system("cls");
            isDone = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "game over" << endl;
            isDone = false;
        }
    } while (isDone);


    system("pause");

    return 0;
    }
```

This is a copy of the assignment.
Note: I am not asking for you guys to do my work. I just want to figure out the highScore sorting thing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question? No one can guess what you're expecting versus what you're actually getting just based on a paragraph of declarative text :)

Comment: Just to start though, I don't think that `scoreName[i = i + 1] = scoreName[i];` does what you think it does. I'd play around with that line (and the similar looking ones) and see how it works.

Comment: You've explained what you want to do, and posted some code. What is your actual question? Is there a problem with the code you posted? If so, what **specifically** is that problem?

Comment: all I am trying to do is figure out, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: actually I should just paste the entire code.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is not asking a specific question.  :-)

Comment: I want to know how do I use a for loop to move elements in an array down .

Comment: just so I can shift my score board down and remove the 10th person when I insert the player score onto the score board

Comment: I want to work from the 9th element in my array and work my way up the list by swapping the position of the other elements in the array with the next element in the array , example the scorename and score in the 9th element gets removed, the 8th is moved to the 9th element, the 7 moved to the 8th element and so on until my player score has been reached, witch replaces the positions in both of my arrays.

Comment: You want to maintain a sorted array of scores and possibly insert a new score into it?

Comment: Thats what i want to do, but when I insert the new score I want to shift the old scores down. because its a top ten score. What ever is in 10th place will get removed and the 9th place will shift down.

Comment: What is the type of `scoreName`? If it is `std::string`, you can copy it with `=`, but if it is `char *` that is more difficult. I assume you can't use standard library containers and algorithms (as it would be very easy to implement with with `std::set`). Also `i = i + 1` is probably the cause of your error.

Comment: scoreName is a string. The i = i+1 was just an experiment I was playing around just trying to get something.

Comment: I just posted up the entire code below, the first snippet of code.

Answer (score 3):

## The problem: arrays are not a good way to achieve what you want

You are trying to see if a score beat another score, and if so, replace that and move the rest of the scores down. I assume your scores are sorted, and that `score` is a `int[10]`, but you have several problems:

1.

```
for (int i = 9; i < leaderBoardSize; i--)
```

You are attempting to iterate through your scores backwards, so you start at `9` (which I assume is the *last index*) and work your way down. Assuming `leaderBoardSize` is the total size of the leaderboard, and likely `10`, `i` will **always** be less than `leaderBoardSize` and your `for` loop will go for a *loooong* time. You probably meant to say:

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
```

2.

```
scoreName[i = i + 1] = scoreName[i];
score[i = i + 1] = score[i];
```

This is **assigning** `i` to a new value, which will also ruin your `for` loop. You should only be doing

```
scoreName[i + 1] = scorename[i];
```

Trying to swap all the values in an array in cumbersome, and you are trying to do everything manually, so I give you:

## The solution: use the standard library!

C++ is a great language, if for no other reason than containing a standard library: a library of functions and classes that solve many basic problems for you.

It is far easier to sort, insert and remove elements by using a standard container. Let's use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

```
// Simple class to handle a player score: a name and score
struct PlayerScore
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int score;
};

// Create some test scores. I assume you have another means of storing high scores, perhaps in a file, but for this small purpose I am just hard-coding some scores:
std::vector<PlayerScore> hiScores = { {"ABC", 5000}, {"XJK", 10000}, {"FOO", 20000}, {"EGG", 4000}, {"HI", 50000} };
```

You may keep your scores sorted, but if, like mine they aren't sorted, you can sort them easily with [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/):

```
std::sort(hiScores.begin(), hiScores.end(), [](PlayerScore ps1, PlayerScore ps2){ return ps1.score > ps2.score; });
```

With that out the way, you can proceed to play your game and obtain a name for the player and their score. I haven't bothered, and will just create a value for the score:

```
auto score = 10123u;
// Check if this score beats any of the current high scores:
auto it = std::find_if(hiScores.begin(), hiScores.end(), [score](PlayerScore ps){ return score > ps.score; });
if (it != hiScores.end())
{
    // Yes! We beat a score!
    std::cout << "Found score: " << it->score << std::endl;
    // Insert this score before the other score
    hiScores.insert(it, {"NewScore", score});
    // Remove the last score:
    hiScores.pop_back();
}
```

You no longer need to iterate and manually try to manipulate the positions of scores. Standard containers with random access such as `std::vector` allow you to just insert and access elements as you need to. Your 10 lines of code simply becomes 2 lines. `std::vector` also manages the size for you, so if you only have 3 high scores initially, it can grow easily to contain 10, 100 or many more scores.

[`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) can find an element in your container without the need to manually iterate over every element. A predicate is passed in which acts as a *find condition*, which in our case we pass our `score` and check if it's greater than any `PlayerScore` in the container. The first element it's greater than is returned to us, and then we can [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) our score in front of it, then remove the last score via [`pop_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/)

Answer (score 0):

> and if so, insert it into the correct position and make sure scoreName is also updated

This is a poor design. If scores and names need to stay together, you should make them a single entity. Define a struct or class to hold a name and associated score, and then store instances of that entity in a single array.